# From a low-level perspective, what is the difference between named pipes and remote procedure calls (RPC) in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, rpc, named-pipes

I'm trying to understand a low-level architecture of Microsoft's implementation of [named pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx) vs [RPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378651(v=vs.85).aspx). I understand that both can be used for client/server communication between applications on a local network. But why would I choose one over another?

PS. Is RPC a higher level implementation built on top of named pipes, or vice versa? I'm also trying to see which one would have less overhead.

Comment: of course RPC a higher level implementation built on top of named pipes or another (usual [a]lpc ports) transport.

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks for clarification. I'm also curious, for named pipes what kind of transport system do they use? Is it just plain TCP/IP? Any built-in encryption?

Comment: look for [Protocol Sequence Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374395(v=vs.85).aspx) - in most case used *ncalrpc* protocol (Local procedure call, [a]lpc). named pipes used if select *ncacn_np*. look also [RpcStringBindingCompose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378481(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: *for named pipes what kind of transport system do they use* - exist special driver in system - *npfs.sys* - he implement named pipes, which is files opened on it device. all this absolute unrelated to TCP/IP

Comment: in general when you write to named pipe file - system copy your data to buffer in kernel memory. when somebody read from this pipe - npfs copy data from this kernel buffer to user buffer (from readfile).

Comment: if kernel buffer not big enough (or 0 size), npfs hold user mode buffer from write request (not complete irp) until somebody not call readfile, for copy data from this buffer. npfs not do any encryption on buffer

Comment: @RbMm: No, I'm talking about named pipes with connections to a remote computer. In that case do you know if the data is encrypted when it's sent over a network? If I open it as `\\192.168.1.2\pipe\pipename`

Comment: think that not encrypted

Comment: Named pipes are implemented by the named pipe file system driver, "\FileSystem\Npfs" using the file system device "\Device\NamedPipe". It implements a single root directory, "\Device\NamedPipe\", for all named pipes (e.g. "\Device\NamedPipe\InitShutdown"). Anonymous pipes are opened relative to a handle for this directory (it used to use a random name for an 'anonymous' pipe). In the Windows API this device is "\\.\PIPE", which is implemented in NT as an object symbolic link from "\GLOBAL??\PIPE" to "\Device\NamedPipe".

Comment: Remote named pipes and mailslots are accessed via SMB (over TCP or NetBIOS over TCP). This is like other filesystem shares, except using the hidden "IPC$" share. See [MS-SMB2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246482) and [MS-CIFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee442092) for more details.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks for the info. I tried to peruse thru those huge PDFs. Am I correct that encryption happens only on later versions of SMB? Also, isn't it the same protocol that was in the news lately as being exploited by the WannaCry and NotPetay malware?

Comment: I don't follow security news as closely as maybe I should, so I can't help with any insight into SMB exploits or how to go about low-level encryption of an SMB connection. Certainly at a high level you could layer your own encryption on data that's passed in RPC calls.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that the network protocol aspects of named pipes aren't implemented in the local npfs.sys driver. Remote file system access is via SMB, and here you're dealing with MUP and the Lanman redirector and server. The redirector rewrites the "PIPE" share name as the actual "IPC$" share and sets the connection type as named pipe. But apparently you can directly open "\\localhost\IPC$\pipename". In Process Explorer you can see that the System process (PID 4) opens the local path "\Device\NamedPipe\pipename".

Comment: @eryksun: True. Although if I have to do all that low-level encryption, then why not just implement a pipe functionality with TLS via TCP/IP using WinSock2.

Answer (score 1):

Named pipes are a communications channel but they don't specify what data is to be sent (in a lot of ways they are a lot like either TCP or UDP on top of IP).

An RPC interface on the other hand specifies what data is needed for a successful communication and what data that communication will produce.

Note that RPC is capable of using a large number of communications channels and named pipes are just one of the possible options.

Comment: Thanks. In a sense though, if named pipes are a lower-level implementation than RPC, they too must be based on something (for a remote server connection.) Wouldn't that be TCP, or UDP internally?

Comment: No, the named pipe protocol can sit on top of IP (and that is the likely choice for any recent version of Windows) but it has no need for either TCP or UDP. NP can also use other (mostly local) protocols such as IPX for transport framing.